# SilverStripe how translate date function in template?

Tags: date, multilingual, silverstripe, fluent

I'm using [Fluent](https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent) module multilanguage support for SilverStripe 3.1 and there is no documentation for using the Date function into Templates.

The file fluent.yml have these configurations :

```
 ---
 Name: myfluentconfig
 After: '#fluentconfig'
 ---
 Fluent:
   default_locale: fr_CA
   locales:
     - en_CA
     - fr_CA
   aliases:
     en_CA: en
     fr_CA: fr
 ---
 Name: myfluenti18nconfig
 After: '#fluenti18nconfig'
 ---
 i18n:
   default_locale: fr_CA
```

I have also remove in mysite/_config.php :

```
 // i18n::set_locale('fr_FR');
```

That work great on my site. But how show dates in correct Language? If my Date variable is $date in my template, I can add $date.month to show the full month. But actually, it only appear in english on fr_CA site. So, Is it possible to show the french date in other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and localisation, a pita for every multilangual developer. [FormatI18N](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-Date.html#143-153) should return the formatted string using [strftime()](http://php.net/strftime) depending on the current locale. It won't work if you have not installed your locale (fr_FR) on your server. Or if you use e.g. fr_FR@utf-8... I had to include this setlocale on a site of mine in *mysite/_config.php* to get it working:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_AT.utf8");
```

and overwrite it later in Page_controller::init(). (It's a translatable based site, fluent does that for you automatically)

So plese check the installed locales on your machine.

Comment: Oh it's dificult to understard your awnser. If think my code example confuse my question.... I update my question.

Comment: well, it might not be your code but server settings causing difficulties here. What OS does your server run on? have you installed the locales you want to use on your server? Please provide some more informations...

Comment: ok, i will check with my server provider and I will come back when I will have the awnser. Thanks

Comment: FormatI18N works but not at 100%. I dont know if its an issue, but special characters show «?» instead. I correct the problem adding a stringparser to encode in UTF8 and that is! Resolve <code>$Date.FormatI18N('%b').UTF8encoding()</code>